# Column hiding using column().visible() in datatable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I have done one application in Django. In that application, I want to hide datatable column based on selection of one flag. I have tried column().visible() method but it is not working. Any suggestions please?

My code is :

```
var table = $('#utmrejectedTable').DataTable();

alert( 'Column index 0 is '+(table.column( 0 ).visible() === true ? 'visible' : 'not visible'));

table.column(0).visible( false );

alert( 'Column index 0 is '+(table.column( 0 ).visible() === true ? 'visible' : 'not visible'));
```

2nd alert says as **not visible** but column is **visible** in front-end.
Is there any better way to hide column? If yes, suggestions please.

Comment: console.log(table.column( 0 ).visible()) gives false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using *columnDefs*

```
...
"columnDefs":
           [
               {
                   "targets": [0],
                   "visible": false,
                   "searchable": false,
               },
...
```

Also make sure the *responsive* parameter for the DataTable is set to false.

Note that you can put logic to the *visible* parameter, for example:

```
visible: data.yourflaghere === 1 ? true : false
```